# ObjectCache pra disponibilizar uma variável para todos os usuários

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, session, cache

Tenho uma aplicação em ASP.NET e gostaria de fazer um cache pra todos os usuários como se a variável ficasse no *pool* de aplicação e todos tivessem acesso,algo diferente da `session` que faz a variável de seção pra cada usuário. `ObjectCache` seria o mais indicado?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse é um exemplo do uso de objectcache a variável fica a disposição de todos no pool de aplicação:

```
if (cache[Cache.Key.PesquisaGrupoProjetos.ToString()] != null)
    grupos = ((IList<EstruturaSIIMDTO>)cache[Cache.Key.PesquisaGrupoProjetos.ToString()]);
else
{
    grupos = db.Get(new ConsultaGrupoProjeto()).ToList();
    cache.Set(Cache.Key.PesquisaGrupoProjetos.ToString(),grupos,DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(720));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

O que é bom para você na situação específica só você poderá dizer. Mesmo que você coloque muitos detalhes ainda pode ser difícil dizer com precisão o que é melhor porque qualquer detalhe omitido, mesmo por desconhecimento dele, pode mudar a recomendação.

Ao que parece você está no caminho certo. Não sei se é o melhor mas usar uma implementação de [`ObjectCache`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.objectcache?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) é algo que vai obter o resultado desejado, desde que feito corretamente, claro.

Só atente ao detalhe que esta é uma classe abstrata, portanto você terá que usar uma implementação concreta dela ou criar sua própria implementação. Provavelmente você quer usar uma existente e parece que quer fazer isto na memória. Então, na prática você usará a [`MemoryCache`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1). Aí toda sua aplicação trabalhará dentro dos protocolos desta classe para lidar com o cache. O que é bom porque ela foi pensada por profissionais que entendem do assunto e sabem como fazer funcionar da melhor forma. Você só deveria fazer sua própria implementação se realmente precisar de algo específico que outra não atende e saiba bem o que está fazendo. Mesmo neste caso, usar a `ObjectCache` como base ainda será desejável.

É bom ver que está evitando outras formas de cache mais específicas como a `System.Web.Caching.Cache` que depende do ASP.NET "clássico" que era uma dependência do ASP.NET MVC mas não é mais nas versões mais novas e o ideal é não usar nada que não seja "universal" do .NET.

Tem outras formas de criar um cache no ASP.NET MVC mas aí depende do que está fazendo. Muitas são bem específicas. Tem opções onde você [anota o cache](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) nas [propriedades definindo no *controller*](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Tem um *framework* de terceiros com diversas opções para cada necessidade.

[Lembrando que o .NET Core é preferível agora](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101).

Answer (score 2):

Se você tem intenção de que seu código seja escalável, então o melhor no caso é usar um banco de dados.

Colocar dados em uma aplicação web, de forma estática, na memória do processo que está servindo uma requisição **não é boa prática**. A não ser que você tenha intenção de implementar um `ObjectCache` que leia e escreva no BD você mesmo, você estará limitado ao `MemoryCache` que faz exatamente o que eu disse anteriormente. (existe uma implementação de `ObjectCache` distribuída chamada `NCache`, leia mais abaixo).

- **O que acontece quando houver mais de um processo atendendo requisições?**
- **O que acontece se houver mais de um servidor, por trás de um balanceador de carga?** Isso acontece na plataforma do Azure por exemplo.

Mas ai você poderia argumentar que o banco de dados é lento... mas a verdade é que não é. A maioria das aplicações lê do banco de dados, em todos os requests. Além disso, é possível usar estratégias de cache em vários níveis: usando memória e banco de dados ao mesmo tempo, quando surgir a necessidade.

A questão é... **por que não começar pelo mais seguro?** Que funciona em todos os casos, e depois a medida do necessário otimizar o cache, migrar para uma abordagem mista, instalar um cabo de fibra óptica entre o servidor web e o servidor de BD, migrar para o Azure, Amazon, etc... são tantas opções para otimizar isso.

### Tecnologias de cache distribuído

São as melhores opções, pois são feitas para funcionar mesmo em ambientes distribuídos.

- [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/): implementação distribuída de `ObjectCache`, possui [versões paga e aberta gratuita](http://www.alachisoft.com/download.html). Inclusive está no [GitHub](https://github.com/Alachisoft/NCache).
- [memcached](http://memcached.org): solução popular de cache distribuído, requer um cliente para .Net:

  - [enyim](https://github.com/enyim/EnyimMemcached): me parece a opção mais forte
  - [nmemcached](https://nmemcached.codeplex.com)
  - [beitmemcached](https://code.google.com/p/beitmemcached/)
- [couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com)

Answer (score 2):

Recomendo, fortemente, que utilize um serviço de Cache, como Redis que o Azure Cache usa.

Assim você garante que o cache irá coexistir mesmo em ambientes escaláveis, e também não mistura as responsabilidades, como usar o banco de dados da aplicação como repositório temporário do seu cache.

Veja mais sobre [Azure Cache](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cache/).

Veja mais sobre [Cache Redis](http://redis.io/).